# Volume of revolving a function around x-axis (washer method)

Tags: calculus

For the sketch given, (using the Washer method)
$$
\begin{aligned}
V &=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \pi\left(R^{2}(x)-r^{2}(x)\right) d x=2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \pi\left(R^{2}(x)-r^{2}(x)\right) d x \\
&=2 \pi \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(1^{2}-(\sqrt{\cos x})^{2}\right) d x \\
&=2 \pi \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(1-\cos x) d x=\left.2 \pi[x-\sin x]\right|_{0} ^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\pi^{2}-2 \pi=3.59
\end{aligned}
$$
[image]

Why do we do ( $1^2 - (\sqrt cos x)^2$) instead of ($\pi^2 -  (\sqrt cos x)^2$) as the bigger radius on x - axis is from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ so that a total distance of the bigger radius of $\pi/2 + \pi/2 = \pi$.

Comment: To  Check my question click ("enter image description") for the question's screenshot , thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Mayar this site recommends that instead of linking to an image of the question, you type it out in your question, as some users are unable to open the attachments.

Comment: @RhysHughes thank you , I'll consider that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is subtract a outer disk to an inner disk therefore the infinitesimal volume is given by

$$dV=(\pi R^2(x)-\pi r^2(x))dx=\pi(R^2(x)-r^2(x))dx=$$

and by symmetry the integral is evaluated twice the one on $(0,\pi/2)$.